# forge.facebook.logout is not clearing the token

Tags: android, facebook, trigger.io

I am using the latest versions of trigger.io (2.2.6) and the facebook module (2.7). The forge.facebook.logout() function runs but when I try and login again it doesn't go back out to facebook but reuses the old access token.

Clearing the data for the app and trying again does go back out to facebook and works as expected.

Comment: R u store access token and expiry in share preferance

Comment: Are you properly using/checking the success and error parameters for forge.facebook.logout? Can you share your code?